# CAUTION: provisional headers are shown

Tags: google-chrome, header, php, http

Привет...
У меня проблема в Chrome.
Запрос вроде не отправляется и в консоли на этом пакете выводится это сообщение.

Что может означать это и по каким причинам:

- Запрос не отправляется?
- Ответ не приходит?
- Сервер не  генерирует ответ на вопрос?

Answer (score 2):

Какое-то расширение блокирует запрос.
Попробуйте запустить Chrome в режиме Инкогнито (Ctrl + Shift + N). Дополнения будут отключены.

Comment: Это блокируется браузером ? Причины блокирования если через интервал идут отправка пакетов....Припустим 12345 - отправились 6 -ошибка 78910 -отправляются дальше

Answer (score 1):

Ресурс может блокироваться расширением

> Сообщение есть, потому что запрос на получение этого ресурса никогда
>   не был выполнен, поэтому отображаемые заголовки не являются
>   реальностью. Как пояснялось в проблеме, на которую вы ссылались,
>   реальные заголовки обновляются, когда сервер отвечает, но нет ответа,
>   если запрос был заблокирован.
>
> Введите `chrome://net-internals` в адресную строку и нажмите enter.
>   Откройте страницу с проблемами. Вернитесь к сетевым внутренним
>   элементам, нажмите events (###) и используйте текстовое поле, чтобы
>   найти событие, связанное с вашим ресурсом (используйте части
>   URL-адреса). Наконец, нажмите на событие и посмотрите, подскажет ли
>   вам информация.